# Is there a way to achieve more than 2 themes (appearances) in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift

In iOS, I would like to enable users to select different themes within the app.

For instance, the following statement will resolve to different color code, based on chosen theme.

```
UIColor(named: "greyNoteColor")!
```

However, iOS only provide 2 different themes (appearances) - Either **Any Appearance** or **Dark Appearance**

[image]

I was wondering, is there a way to support more than 2 themes in iOS app?

For instance, in Android, I can support more than 2 themes by using the following strategy.

```
<style name="Theme.WeNote.Red" parent="@style/Theme.WeNote.Base.Brown">
    <item name="greyNoteColor">#040404</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.WeNote.Purple" parent="@style/Theme.WeNote.Base.Brown">
    <item name="greyNoteColor">#030303</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.WeNote.Blue" parent="@style/Theme.WeNote.Base.Brown">
    <item name="greyNoteColor">#020202</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.WeNote.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="greyNoteColor">#010101</item>
</style>

setTheme(R.style.Theme_WeNote_Red)
TypedValue typedValue = new TypedValue();
Resources.Theme theme = getTheme();
theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.greyNoteColor, typedValue, true);

//
// Will resolve to color code #040404
//
int greyNoteColor = typedValue.data;
```

I was wondering, how can we achieve the similar behaviour is iOS app?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by code using the following approach:

```
public static let myColor: UIColor = {
    let theme = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "theme")
    if (theme == "RED") {
        return UIColor.red
    } else if (theme == "GREEN") {
        return UIColor.green
    }
    
    // any other cases
    
    return UIColor.white
}()
```